# How to run a Python unit test with the Atom editor?

Tags: python, unit-testing, atom-editor

I'm trying out the Atom editor and was wondering how I can run Python unit tests with a keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Installation**

1. Install the [Atom](https://atom.io) editor
2. Install the [Script](https://atom.io/packages/script) package like this:

   a) Start Atom

   b) Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, type "install packages and themes" and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to open the package view

   c) Search for "script" and install the package

**Unit test example test.py**

3. Write a unit test and save it as `test.py`.

   ```
   import unittest

   class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):

     def test_pass(self):
         pass

     def test_fail(self):
         call_method_that_does_not_exist()

   if __name__ == '__main__':
   unittest.main()
   ```

**Run unit test**

4. Now, press [<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>](https://atom.io/packages/script#command-and-shortcut-reference) to run the Python script ([see documentation](https://atom.io/packages/script#command-and-shortcut-reference))

**Console output**

Because the unit test `test_fail` will fail, this will be the console output:

```
E.
======================================================================
ERROR: test_fail (__main__.MyTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Lernkurve/Desktop/PythonDemos/a.py", line 9, in test_fail
    call_method_that_does_not_exist()
NameError: global name 'call_method_that_does_not_exist' is not defined

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.000s

FAILED (errors=1)
[Finished in 0.047s]
```

Comment: Works great! I use it with pytest so I added code to start the test run: `if __name __ == '__main__': pytest.main([__file__, '--color=yes'])`

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [Atom Python Test](https://atom.io/packages/atom-python-test) plug-in. It supports:

- Run the test under cursor
- Run all tests of a module
- Run doc tests

It also supports adding additional arguments to test execution and allows to run unitttest.TestCase too.